# Calling shopify API from Postman

Tags: php, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app

I need to create a webhook in shopify using Postman.
I have entered following:

**Method**: POST

**URL**: `https://{{api_key}}:{{api_password}}@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json`

**Parameters**:

```
{
    "topic": "order/creation",
    "address": "https://example.com/shopify_app/order_created.php"
}
```

**Headers**:
`[{"key":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","description":""}]`

I have replaced `{{api_key}}` with API key created while creating the app, and `{{api_password}}` with the access_token.

When I hit this, I get "Please log in" screen. Please check below image:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Seems to you not passing shopify token to your postman request. So please pass "X-**Shopify-Access-Token** " to  request header

[image]

It will solve your problem

Comment: Quite new to REST API in general. I got the api_key and api_password from creating a private app in Shopify, how do I get the Shopify Token?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah this seems weird. Most probably you're sending cookies with your request.

Click on `Cookies` below to the send button and clear all the cookies and try to make POST request again. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

The URL has to be the same format as yours.

**URL:** https://{{api_key}}:{{api_password}}@{{store_name}}.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json

But have to enter the arguments in the Postman like this:

**Key** = **Value**

webhook[topic] = orders/create

webhook[address] = https://whatever.hostname.com/

webhook[format] = json

*( to build that json format logic into the post data )*

[image: Image from Postman]

Comment: It seems that you are not entering the information right.
Can you attach the fullscreen of the program, not just the response?
Use some dummy data for example.